# MongoDB - Getting distinct values of a column after a group by on another column is applied

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo table that has Year, Author and _id (let's say). All I need to do is to filter on a particular year (say 2006), perform group by on the Author and get a list of unique _id's for every author. Author is an array.

A snapshot of my table is as below

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54898fbb306ba2153c3e637b"),
  "Author": [
    "Hullman, J.",
    "Drucker, S.",
    "Riche, N.H.",
    "Bongshin Lee",
    "Fisher, D.",
    "Adar, E."
  ],
  "Year": "2013"
}{
  "_id": ObjectId("54898fbb306ba2153c3e637c"),
  "Author": [
    "Schulz, H.",
    "Nocke, T.",
    "Heitzler, M.",
    "Schumann, H."
  ],
  "Year": "2013",
}{
  "_id": ObjectId("54898fbc306ba2153c3e6b58"),
  "Author": [
    "Boissonnat, J.-D.",
    "Geiger, B."
  ],
  "Year": "1993",
}
```

The query that I have till now is as follows.

```
db.list_input_file.aggregate([
  {'$match':{'Year':{$eq:'2006'}}},
  {'$unwind':'$Author'},
  {'$group':{'_id':'$Author', 'count': { '$sum': 1 }}}
])
```

All I need is a output of the format [{"Author Name":[list of ids]}, {"Author Name":[list of ids]}]

Comment: So show your document. What content is in the "Author" array. My money is you're actually using Mongoose and this is an array of document references.

Comment: I was able to find the solution. See my answer posted below. Thanks!

Comment: Then perhaps you should show some data to explain my your answer is valid. People cannot determine this by what you have posted. This is a question and answer site. There is not enough detail in your question to justify the answer.

Comment: I apologize for the incomplete question. I have posted more details of the same in both my question and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had to use the [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) accumalator operator to get the ids. My final query is as follows

```
db.list_input_file.aggregate([
 {'$match':{'Year':{$eq:'2006'}}},
 {'$unwind':'$Author'},
 {'$group':{'_id':'$Author', 'count': { '$sum': 1 }, 'ids':{$addToSet:'$_id'}}}
])
```

And a snapshot of the output of the above query is shown below.

```
{ "_id" : "Hofacker, I.L.", "ids" : [ ObjectId("54898fbb306ba2153c3e66e4") ] }
{ "_id" : "Flamm, C.", "ids" : [ ObjectId("54898fbb306ba2153c3e66e4") ] }
{ "_id" : "Heine, C.", "ids" : [ ObjectId("54898fbb306ba2153c3e66e4") ] }
{ "_id" : "MacEachren, A.M.", "ids" : [ ObjectId("54898fbb306ba2153c3e66dd") ] }
{ "_id" : "Card, S.K.", "ids" : [ ObjectId("54898fbb306ba2153c3e66d4"), ObjectId("54898fbb306ba2153c3e66ca") ] }
```